# Does the following limit of the function exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ is rational number} \\[2ex]
-1, & \text{if $n$ is irrational number}
\end{cases}$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \ln(x^{\lvert x\rvert}).\exp(f(x))$

I know that f(x) is bounded, in first look it seems that the limit is zero, but I suspect of the limit existence because of the natural logarithm domain.

Comment: ...and the question is...? Where's the self work, effort, insights....? That $\;|x|\;$ power is on the logarithm's argument or on the logarithm itself?

Comment: I amended it :)

Comment: As you know $\lim\limits_{x\to1} |x| \log x = 0$ and like $\lim\limits_{x\to1}e\cdot|x| \log x = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to1}e^{-1}\cdot |x| \log x = 0$ as well. You might use the definition of limit by sequences to show, that the limit of your function exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x^{|x|}$ is continuous in $1$,
$$\lim_{x\to1}x^{|x|}=1$$
and hence
$$\lim_{x\to1}e^{f(x)}\cdot\ln(x^{|x|})$$
exists and equals $0$ because $e^{f(x)}$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\to1}\ln(x^{|x|})=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to1}x^{|x|}\right)=0$.

Comment: Does $u^v$ if u is negative, defiens for  $v \notin z+?$

Comment: There are some definitions using the complex logarithm, but that isn't relevant here because we only need $u$'s in a neighbourhood of $1$.